# Why is [la] widely used as a substitution for singing? Is it a worldwide phenomenon?

Tags: phonology, psycholinguistics

When people sing without knowing or using the text, they often sing as lalalala...

Comment: It is quite widespread in my experience, though *why* is a mystery to me.

Comment: This would probably be better asked at [music.se].

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music

Comment: Probably because low vowels (a) and laterals (l, r) are the phones that allow air to flow more freely?

Comment: /a/ is easy to explain; it's the most open, resonant vowel.  A sonorant consonant is easy to explain; you need a continuous, non-noisy, periodic sound to carry pitches and melodies. Why the specific sonorant is /l/ is more speculative. It could be /n/, /m/, /j/ which are, indeed, also common in this role; perhaps /l/ is simpler than /m,n/ because you don't have to open and close the nasal passage. To my personal taste /l/ sounds *beautiful*, though that’s probably a consequence of the properties that also make it useful for music, and not the *cause* of its use in music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why la is used widely as a non-lexical vocable (it could be an arbitrary selection that gained popularity), but I can tell you it is not a worldwide phenomenon.

In Indian Classical music, there is a segment called [alap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alap) (or [alapana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alapana)) which is non-rhythmic improvisation done without lyrics. Typically, the singer says *"aaa..."* as he vocalizes (other vowels are used, albeit very rarely). In other variants such as the [nomtom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomtom) (or [tanam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanam)) use nonsensical syllables such as *nom, tom, na, tana, rana*, and so on.

In fact, there is whole a class of (rhythmic) compositions called [taranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarana), which are entirely made up of meaningless syllables.

Comment: Ditto the "terirem" of Byzantine music, which sound just like taranas. Duncan Whyte linked to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-lexical_vocables_in_music, and @boiko referenced sonorants, and that's more on point: sonorants and "a" are going to be more frequent, and "la" is just the choice of sonorant + vowel that the hegemonic culture has made...